# Using two diferent tickets and airlines

Tags: international-travel

I'm going on vacation in Europe, for three weeks ,august 2nd.using one ticket (Lufthansa). but instead of coming back with Lufthansa, on august 20th, I extend my vacation 3 more weeks and coming back with a ticket which I purchase from Turkish air line, good from august 22nd . to September 10th.So, I'm not using the return Lufthansa ticket, and I'm not using the going to Europe ticket , with the Turkish airline, but using the return ticket , Turkish on September 10th.Iknow , I'm losing money ,and I want to know if is possible. This arrangement.
best regards

Comment: Will you be a no-snow for the first flight on the Turkish airline?

Answer (score 7):

You can't use a return, if you don't take the outbound flight. If you don't show up for any leg of an itinerary, the airline will cancel all remaining flights.

In your case: Not taking  the return with Lufthansa is fine.

However, if you don't fly with Turkish on Aug 22, Turkish will cancel your ticket and you can't fly on Sep 10th.